# "TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'next')"

Tags: javascript, linked-list

**Input:** Given two non-empty linked lists representing two non-negative integers. The digits are stored in reverse order, and each of their nodes contains a single digit. Add the two numbers and return the sum as a linked list.

[Input & Output Illustration (open for understanding)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SO32Q.png)

```
var addTwoNumbers = function(l1, l2) {
let carry = 0,
    sum = 0;
let runningNode = new ListNode(0, null);
let headNode = runningNode;

while (l1 !== null || l2 !== null) {

    sum = l1 != null ? l1.val : 0 + l2 != null ? l2.val : 0 + carry;
    carry = 0;
    // Error is in below line it states "TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'next')" 
    runningNode.next = ListNode(sum % 10, null)
    runningNode = runningNode.next;
    //How to fix it?
    if (l1) {
        l1.next;
    }
    if (l2) {
        l2.next;
    }
}

if (carry) {
    runningNode.next = ListNode(carry);
}

return headNode;
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues:

- When calling the constructor, `new` is needed, otherwise `this` is undefined and references like `this.next` are invalid. This correction is needed at two places in your code.
- In the assignment to `sum`, the `+` operator has precedence over the `? :` operator, but in your case you want it the other way, so you need to add parentheses.
- The `carry` is never set to anything else than 0. It should get 1 when the sum is greater than 9.
- The final result will always return a list that starts with 0, which is a dummy node that `head` refers to. This makes the result ten times too large. Return the next node.

Corrected code:

```
var addTwoNumbers = function(l1, l2) {
    let carry = 0,
        sum = 0;
    let runningNode = new ListNode(0, null);
    let headNode = runningNode;
    while (l1 !== null || l2 !== null) {
        // Use parentheses to make sure the addition happens last:
        sum = (l1 != null ? l1.val : 0) + (l2 != null ? l2.val : 0) + carry;
        // Need to set carry
        carry = Math.floor(sum / 10); 
        // Need "new" when calling constructor
        runningNode.next = new ListNode(sum % 10, null); 
        runningNode = runningNode.next;
        // Must assign!
        if (l1) {
            l1 = l1.next;
        }
        if (l2) {
            l2 = l2.next;
        }
    }
    if (carry) {
        // Must call with "new":
        runningNode.next = new ListNode(carry);
    }
    return headNode.next; // skip the zero node
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much Trincot sir. I really appreciate your help.